# HTML 5 : about stream and Chrome

Tags: html, video, mediastreamsource, webrtc

I'm sorry I have a very bad English so be nice with my spelling :)

I'm looking for a video recorder in HTML5 and I found my happiness with getUserMedia of HTML5.

The problem is that `getUserMedia` require that user activate `MediaStream` (for webRTC) on `Chrome's` interface : chrome://flags/

My question is : is it possible to activate this option by asking the user like in javascript ok with an url like `chrome::/flags/mediastream=true` or a function like `setUserMedia`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No.  The user has to turn it on manually.  If you wait a few releases it may get turned on by default.

Answer (score 0):

We can't change [chrome flags switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) within/through JavaScript ---

[*There are command line flags (or "switches") that Chromium accepts in order to enable particular features or modify otherwise default functionality*.](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags/)

It is good practice to **LINK** this page whenever you want to tell end users to enable "**Peer Connection**" switch - http://www.webrtc.org/running-the-demos (in case you're using **PeerConnection** APIs!!!)

**Chromium 21 stable** enables this feature (**getUserMedia**) by default - http://caniuse.com/stream